# jquery & radio button

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I'm trying to make a very simple thing in jquery, which isn't working.

i have this radio button:

```
<input type="radio" id="price" name="shipping" class="styled" />
```

and in Head i have this code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$("input[name=shipping]").change(function() {
    alert("123");
});

});
```

What's wrong with my code?

perhaps it's because i'm using "custom checkboxes and radio buttons"?
http://ryanfait.com/resources/custom-checkboxes-and-radio-buttons/

Comment: [Your code is OK](http://jsfiddle.net/DwMq7/). I don't know this plugin. Did you try without the `class=styled` ? Do you import jQuery **before** your script ?

Comment: i think plugin have bind events on the radio ;) and i am right the plugin have bind events on radio button

Comment: I don't think a plugin would remove the existing binding (jQuery uses addEventListener and don't remove the existing ones). That would make it useless.

Comment: please add, full code ;)

Comment: did you added jquery lib before this script ?

Comment: i have deleted class="styled" and now it's working. do you know how i can use class="styled" and also use jquery?

Answer (score 1):

Your code in correct, But maybe problem is from another where.

Check with   **[firebug](https://addons.mozilla.org/en/firefox/addon/firebug) console**

Answer (score 0):

I had a look at the script you import.

It looks very dated and it contains things like

```
inputs[a].onchange = Custom.clear;
```

This removes the event listeners you added before.

My suggestions would be, in order of preferences :

1. remove this plugin which was probably made only for static pages
2. put your own script at end of body instead of inside the header

Comment: see my comment above please.

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks okay. 
**[JS-BIN Demo](http://jsbin.com/ilaqih/1/edit)**
Make sure you give same name to the radio buttons:

```
<div>
  <input type="radio" id="price1" name="shipping" class="styled" />
  <input type="radio" id="price2" name="shipping" class="styled" />
</div>
```

And your code will work.

Another way is to use click instead of change:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("input[name=shipping]").click(function() {
    alert("123");
});  
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$(document).delegate("input[name=shipping]", "change", function() {
   alert('abc');
});
```